# Accessing Elements in a 3D tensor with 0 lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I have a tensor in Tensor Flow that is of the size (2, 16384, 11).  I am trying to use the tf.slice function to pull 1D tensors out of that array.  I can name two point in the array as the start and stop.

- The first column is [0, 0, 1]  ---> [0, 16383, 1].
- The second column is [1, 0, 1]  ---> [1, 16383, 1].

But the problem is this returns a tensor with the dimensions of (0, 16383) and (1, 16383).  Accessing an array with a length 0 is a problem;  I understand that you can get there by only using the [:] accessor as opposed to the [0] accessor, otherwise you get the error

> '0 is out of bounds for axis 0 of length 0'.

How else can I get TF to output a single column of numbers?  Here is the code.

```
Xdata = tf.slice(x, [0,0,1], [0,16383,1])
Ydata = tf.slice(x, [1,0,1], [1,16383,1])

Xarry = Xdata.numpy()
Yarry = Ydata.numpy()
                         # Outputs
print(Xarry.shape)       # (0, 16383, 1)
print(Yarry.shape)       # (1, 16383, 1)
print(Xarry[:,:,0])      # []
print(Yarry[0,:,0])      # [22.05 20.92 22.11 ... 22.53 22.03 22.47]

plt.plot(Xarry[:,:,0],Yarry[0,:,0])  # <--- Error is here
```

Which produces:

> (0, 16383, 1)
> (1, 16383, 1)
> []
> [22.05 20.92 22.11 ... 22.53 22.03 22.47]
>
> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes
> (0, 16383) and (16383,)

I have tried using .flatten() but this does not get around the problem.  I have also looked at using tf.gather().

Answer (score 0):

`Xarry` shape is `(0, 16383, 1)`, which means an **empty list**, since **the first dimension is zero**. So, if you print it you will get `[]`. As it has nothing to present, then slicing like `Xarry[:,:,0]` will also give you another `[]`.

I think you have a misunderstanding of `tf.slice` arguments. The second argument is the size of tensor, beginning from the first argument index. **The second argument in `tf.slice()` is not the stop index, but the size.**

So, consider to change the size to something like this:

```
Xdata = tf.slice(x, [0,0,1], [1,16383,1]) # start from [0,0,1] index and slice an array with size (1,16383,1)
Ydata = tf.slice(x, [1,0,1], [1,16383,1])

Xarry = Xdata.numpy()
Yarry = Ydata.numpy()
                         # Outputs
print(Xarry.shape)       # (0, 16383, 1)
print(Yarry.shape)       # (1, 16383, 1)
print(Xarry[0,:,0])      # [22.05 20.92 22.11 ... 22.53 22.03 22.47]
print(Yarry[0,:,0])      # [22.05 20.92 22.11 ... 22.53 22.03 22.47]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(Xarry[0,:,0],Yarry[0,:,0])  
plt.show()
```